# Operators invoked multiple times for merged Observable although only one source emits

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a function in which I'm calling an instance of `Manager`'s `onSpecificData()` to which I'm subscribing in order to update my application's state (I'm managing a state on the server-side as well).

The problem is that in the `SomeManager`'s implementation of `onSpecificData()` I'm merging 3 different `Observable`s using `merge()` operator, which for some reason triggers the invocation of all the underlying `Observable`'s operators even though only 1 of the sources is the one that's emitting a value

**SomeManager.ts**

```
export class DerivedManager implements Manager {
    private driver: SomeDriver;

    constructor(...) {
        this.driver = new SomeDriver(...);
    }

    public onSpecificData(): Observable<DataType> {
        return merge(
            this.driver.onSpecificData(Sources.Source1).map((value) => {
                return {source1: value};
            }),
            this.driver.onSpecificData(Sources.Source2).map((value) => {
                return {source2: value};
            }),
            this.driver.onSpecificData(Sources.Source3).map((value) => {
                return {source3: value};
            })
        );
    }
```

**Manager.ts**

```
export type DataType = Partial<{value1: number, value2: number, value3: number}>;

export interface Manager {
    onSpecificData(): Observable<DataType>;
}
```

**SomeDriver.ts**

```
export const enum Sources {
    Source1,
    Source2,
    Source3,
}

export class SomeDriver extends Driver {
    private static specificDataId = 1337; // some number

    private handler: Handler;

    constructor(...) {
        super(...);
        this.handler = new Handler(this.connection, ...);
        // ...
    }

    // ...

   onSpecificData(source: Sources): Observable<number> {
       return this.handler
           .listenToData<SpecificDataType>(
               SomeDriver.specificDataId,
               (data) => data.source === source)
           ).map((data) => data.value);
   }
}
```

**Driver.ts**

```
export abstract class Driver {
     protected connection: Duplex;

     constructor(...) {
         // init connection, etc...
     }

     public abstract onSpecificData(source: number);

     // some implementations and more abstract stuff...
}
```

**Handler.ts**

```
export class Handler {
    private data$: Observable<Buffer>;

    constructor(private connection: Duplex, ...) {
        this.data$ = Observable.fromEvent<Buffer>(connection as any, 'data');
    }

    listenToData<T>(dataId: number, filter?: (data: T) => boolean) {
        return this.data$
            .map((data) => {
                 // decode and transform
            })
            .filter((decodedData) => !decodedData.error && decodedData.value.id)
            .do((decodedData) => {
                 console.log(`Got ${decodedData.value.id}`);
            })
            .map((decodedData) => decodedData.value.value as T)
            .filter(filter || () => true);
    }
}
```

And finally, `subscribe()`-ing:

```
export default function(store: Store<State>, manager: Manager) {
    // ...

    manager.onSpecificData()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            // update state according to returned data
        });
}
```

As you can see, there is only **1** underlying `Observable` (`data$`) but apparently the operator chain in `listenToData<T>()` is invoked **3** times *for each value* emitted by it. I already know this is because of `SomeManager#onSpecificData()`'s `merge` of those 3 `Observable`s, but I don't know why this happens. I want it to be invoked once for each value.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You call `onSpecificData` three times with three different arguments which returns `this.handler.listenToData` three times. So what you don't understand?

Comment: I call it three times but only `subscribe()` once, to the merged observable. I'd expect the operator chain to be called once for the source observable which emitted the value, not three times.

Comment: No, because when you call `onSpecificData()` 3 times you create 3 different observables (you have three different chains).

Comment: True, but I'm merging them, and only one of them emitted a value. It'd make sense that the one which emitted a value would be the only observable whose chain is invoked.

Comment: zip, forjoin will give you one emission. but merge will fire whichever inner observable fires.

Comment: `zip` and `forkJoin` only emit upon completion, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a "hacky" way, in my opinion.  I replaced `data$` with a `Subject`, created an observable from `stream`'s `'data'` event, moving all the shared logic to that observable and emit a value from the subject, like so:

```
export class Handler {
    private dataSrc = new Subject<DecodedData>();

    constructor(private connection: Duplex, ...) {
        Observable.fromEvent<Buffer>(connection as any, 'data')
            .map((data) => {
                 // decode and transform
            })
            .filter((decodedData) => !decodedData.error)
            .do((decodedData) => {
                 console.log(`Got ${decodedData.value.id}`);
            })
            .subscribe((decodedData) => {
                this.dataSrc.next(decodedData);
            });
    }

    listenToData<T>(dataId: number, filter?: (data: T) => boolean) {
        return this.dataSrc
            .filter((decodedData) => decodedData.value.id === dataId)
            .map((decodedData) => decodedData.value.value as T)
            .filter(filter || () => true);
    }
}
```

Not exactly the solution I was looking for, but it works. If anyone has a better solution, which better suits the "Rx way" to do stuff, I'd love to hear it.